# Split array by input() if remaining list size < input(), split with remaining

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do i split a numpy array by input(), however if there is not enough values to evenly split, just split with the remaining values

Example for clarity:

```
Arr = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 9])
```

if the user inputs 3 split the array by 3 but if there are not enough values to evenly split, just put the remaining values in one split

```
#Output
[[1, 2, 4], [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you looking for something like this?

```
N = 3
np.array_split(Arr, range(N, len(Arr), N))
```

From here: [How to split a numpy array into arrays with specific number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294320/how-to-split-a-numpy-array-into-arrays-with-specific-number-of-elements)